# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException when adding/updating OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, one-to-many

I'm using one to many relationship with hibernate and spring boot and I'm getting this error
when adding a new company or updating a company

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'activity' cannot be null
```

and the same error when adding a new contact or updating a contact

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'fk_company' cannot be null
```

My Entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;  
    @Column(name = "activity", nullable = false)
    private String activity;
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "logo", nullable = true)
    private String logo;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
}   

@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;   
    @Column(name = "phone", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long phone;
    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "job", nullable = false)
    private String job;
    @Column(name = "birthday", nullable = true)
    private Date birthday;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_company", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Company company;
}
```

Here is the code of save/update a company or a contact

```
@RestController
public class CompanyRestService {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/companies", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Company save(Company c){
        return companyRepository.save(c);
   }
   @RequestMapping(value="/companies/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
   @ResponseBody
   public Company update(@PathVariable Long id, Company c){
       c.setId(id);
       return companyRepository.save(c);
   }
}

ving @RestController
public class ContactRestService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;

      @RequestMapping(value="/contacts", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Contact save(Contact c){
        return contactRepository.save(c);
       }
      @RequestMapping(value="/contacts/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public Contact update(@PathVariable Long id, Contact c){
        c.setId(id);
        return contactRepository.save(c);
       }
}
```

I already tried to save and update a contact without "OneToMany" Mapping and it did work for me, i'm wondering if it's a mapping problem?
Do you have an idea of what can cause this problem?

[Github project link](https://github.com/Myung5/vi-crm)

Comment: It's not a mapping problem. Your request data missing activity key when you are saving company. So check your requested data.

Comment: but the primary key is AUTO INCREMENT so there is no need to add it when saving a new record.

Comment: Yes, But activity is not your primary key. Your primary key is id in company table. Can you share the json data which you are sending to save company?